# Error when trying to pass image source from a component to its child component

Tags: react-native

I'm currently creating a small example of React Native. The issue I'm having is that when I tried to pass the image source from my LoginScreen component to ImageHolder component, the Node shows error below:

```
Loading dependency graph, done.
error: bundling failed: Error: src\ImageHolder.js:Invalid call at line 7: require({
  imageSource: imageSource
})
    at C:\Users\Kuro\vuichoi_ui\node_modules\metro\src\JSTransformer\worker.js:247:19
at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
at step (C:\Users\Kuro\vuichoi_ui\node_modules\metro\src\JSTransformer\worker.js:40:30)
at C:\Users\Kuro\vuichoi_ui\node_modules\metro\src\JSTransformer\worker.js:51:15
```

Here is my code:

LoginScreen.js render:

```
render() {
        if (true) {
            return (
                <View>
                    <LoginText
                        imgSource="./img/account.png"
                        secureOption={false}
                        value={this.state.username}
                        placeholder="username"
                        onChangeText={username => this.setState(username)}
                    />
                </View>
            )
        }
    }
```

LoginText.js:

```
const LoginText = ({imgSource, secureOption, placeholder, value, onChangeText}) => {

    return (
        <View style={styles.containerStyle}>
            <ImageHolder imageSource={imgSource} />
            <InputField placeholder={placeholder} secureOption={secureOption} value={value} onChangeText={onChangeText}/>
        </View>
    )
}
```

ImageHolder.js:

```
const ImageHolder = ({imageSource}) => {
    return (
     <View style={styles.imgContainerStyle}>
            <Image source={require(imageSource)}></Image>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: Could you add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in the path of Image. If all the component on the same path then you can the same thing.

The solutions is that you need to pass Image from **LoginScreen.js**

```
render() {
        if (true) {
            return (
                <View>
                    <LoginText
                        imgSource={require('./img/account.png')}
                        secureOption={false}
                        value={this.state.username}
                        placeholder="username"
                        onChangeText={username => this.setState(username)}
                    />
                </View>
            )
        }
    }
```

**ImageHolder.js**

```
const ImageHolder = ({imageSource}) => {
    return (
     <View style={styles.imgContainerStyle}>
            <Image source={imageSource}></Image>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Replace the code above tow js and it will work for you.